# Stripe: How To Avoid Calling The API Too Often?

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am building a (small) subscription box business and I now need to focus on the web app. I already built stripe-based websites so I have a decent knowledge.

However, the issue I faced when building these previous sites is that **the API was called TOO OFTEN**. It slowed everything down.

How to build this subscription-based website, only with stripe, and **making calls to Stripe API only when required** (create/edit a customer, plan, subscription, etc.) while still **making sure information is reconciled and up-to-date** on the website for both admin and clients?

Comment: What do you mean by too often?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the Stripe Webhook API here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks

You can store the user's information in the database and only update those fields if the user makes a UI action and you can make an assumption on what to update (like a subscription plan ID) or using a webhook handler, which you can use as a sanity check as well.

To be even more specific, I can give some examples as you will still need to make API calls when a user does an action such as: creates an account, removes their subscription, subscribes to a different subscription. You will store when their subscription expires in the database. When the user makes a request you do not make an API call to check when their subscription expires, but check the database field. When the subscription renews itself you will then have a webhook handler to update the expiration date in the database.

Essentially how it works is Stripe will make a request to YOUR service only when it needs to, instead of your service calling to Stripe on every request.

For WordPress specifically you can user the User Meta Data to cache/store the user's information and only make calls to your database for faster transactions. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Comment: You understand the question? I don't.

Comment: Yes, his issue is that by using Stripe's REST API you have to wait until Stripe returns a response before the server will respond to the user. This is very bad for performance and the user essentially has to wait for 2 HTTP requests before getting a response. By using the webhooks you eliminate an entire HTTP request by making your system more reactive. A case where you would need to make a REST call would be when a user creates their account or subscribes to a new subscription.

Comment: Great, exactly what I wanted. Didn't realise about the webhooks! Everything initiated by the user will generate an API call, everything automated by Stripe will generate them to cally webhook and I can then update the relevant user meta for essential info!